# Questions and answers are all skewed - can't read

Tags: bug, android-app

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S3 Android version 4.0.4 and Stack Exchange version 1.0.51. After one of the updates (not sure which one) all of the questions and answers appear skewed. Sometimes they are just blank, or all squished together. I basically can't even use the app.

Attached is an example:

[image: screen shot]